# Перемещение по слайдеру с помощью лкм и drag

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как добавить возможность перемещения по слайдеру с помощью лкм и drag, как [здесь](http://pleinair.myinsales.ru/?_ga=2.249607238.139716607.1588630234-1716321393.1588630234)? На чистом js, пожалуйста. 
Cпасибо.

Comment: https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ у этого слайдера как то не так работает ?

Comment: Эта библиотека безусловно прекрасна. Но я бы хотел узнать, как делать то же самое, но на чистом JS, чтобы иметь понимание. Какой смысл использовать библиотеку, упрощающую жизнь, если не понимаешь как она работает?

Comment: я могу ошибиться но мне кажется что ни кто  не будет это делать

Comment: Хотите сказать, что это совершенно естественно использовать библиотеки везде, где только можно без понимание их работы?

Comment: ну смотрите - есть программисты - они очень хорошо пишут js и целая команда создаёт этот slick.js - наверняка на so тоже есть крутой js специалист но он всё равно слабее команды ...я прав ?

Comment: Наверное, вы правы. Но в любом случае, хотя бы какой-то анализ расширяет знания, особенно на старте. Пусть я и не сделаю новый slick.js. но понимать js стану лучше.

Comment: Я располагаю достаточным количеством знаний чтобы не приходилось пользоваться библиотеками для таких простых вещей как слайдер. Если человек действительно хочет разобраться это хорошо, но он должен хотя бы начать это делать, а не просить других.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

примерный вариант наскоряк

```js
var start = 0;
var slid = document.getElementById("slider");
var sdvig = window.innerWidth;
var position = 0;

slid.addEventListener("dragstart",drag_start,false);
slid.addEventListener("dragend",drag_stop,false);
slid.addEventListener("drag",drag,false);

function drag_start(e){
  start = e.screenX;
}
function drag(e){
  let p = position - (start - e.screenX);
  slid.style.left = p + "px";
}
function drag_stop(e){
  if(start > e.screenX){
    if(position>-sdvig*2) position -= sdvig;
    slid.style.left = position + "px";
  }else{
    if(position<0) position += sdvig;
    slid.style.left = position + "px";
  }
}
```

```css
div{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
#vidimo{
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
   overflow:hidden;
   position: relative;
}
#slider{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  width: 300%;
  height: 100wh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
#d1{
  background: red;
}
#d2{
  background: blue;
}
#d3{
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="vidimo">
  <div id="slider"> 
    <div id="d1" draggable="true"></div>
    <div id="d2" draggable="true"></div>
    <div id="d3" draggable="true"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```